# Batch blit vs separate blit

Tags: python, pygame

A tutorial that I have followed had me collect and blit all of my sprites with the following lines:

```
allsprites = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain((l_sprites))
allsprites.draw()
```

At the moment, this is fine for me, as all of my sprites make use of the same base image.
However, I find myself in need of having various sprites animated, some changing, and some going to a basic colored rectangle.

My question is if this batch drawing method is still viable when all of my sprites are in flux.  My previous experience has been in straight C with SDL, and normally I would simply roll my own update loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Group` class (for which `RenderPlain` has been a deprecated alias for many years) is more a logical tool than a performance tool. It provides no speed benefit over looping over the sprites yourself. If you are constructing it every frame, it's definitely a net negative.

What you should do instead is replace your `l_sprites` list of sprites with a group directly. Rather than appending sprites to the list, add them to the group. This lets you use [Group.update](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#Group.update) to update the sprites rather than rolling your own update loop. It also lets sprites remove themselves from the group using [Sprite.kill](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#Sprite.kill), which is often a more convenient way to remove them.

If you want a performance gain out of using sprite groups, you should turn to [RenderUpdates](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates), which returns a list of rectangles appropriate for passing to [pygame.display.update](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update).

(If you want good performance, you should give up Pygame's sprite library and turn to OpenGL or one of its Python wrappers instead.)

Comment: I guess this can become a separate question...but OpenGL is better at performance than SDL?  I've always been curious but never knew any background on the differences between the two (we did SDL in college)